# Trying to make simple minesweeper game in python

Tags: python

Trying to make simple minesweeper game in python, but have one problem. 
I have a 7x7 board of x's and when the player enters a row and column it deletes the column
and replaces it with a -. I also tried to have a 1 appear if the players guess one space away, but its not working and I can't figure out why. Instead it ends the loop. Below is what I have done. Its probably a simple fix but i cant see it. Thanks for the help! 
print("Welcome to Minesweeper/n")

```
import random

LA=["X","X","X","X","X","X","X"]
LB=["X","X","X","X","X","X","X"]
LC=["X","X","X","X","X","X","X"]
LD=["X","X","X","X","X","X","X"]
LE=["X","X","X","X","X","X","X"]
LF=["X","X","X","X","X","X","X"]
LG=["X","X","X","X","X","X","X"]


print("", LA, "\n" , LB, "\n" , LC, "\n" , LD, "\n" , LE, "\n" ,
      LF, "\n" , LG, "\n")
print("\n select row starting from top = 1 and column from left = 0")
numa = random.randint(1,7)
numb = random.randint(0,6)
MINE = "O"

row=9
column = 9
one = "1"
blank = "-"

while row != numa and column != numb:
    print("", LA, "\n" , LB, "\n" , LC, "\n" , LD, "\n" , LE, "\n" ,
      LF, "\n" , LG, "\n")
    #cheeter
    print(numa , "" , numb) 
    row = int(input("\nEnter row"))
    column = int(input("\nEnter column"))
    columA = column + 1
    columB = column - 1
    rowA = row + 1
    rowB = row - 1
    if rowA == numa and column  == numb:
        if row ==1:
            del LA[column]
            LA.insert(column, one)
        if row ==2:
            del LB[column]
            LB.insert(column, one)     
        if row ==3:
            del LC[column]
            LC.insert(column, one)   
        if row ==4:
            del LD[column]
            LD.insert(column, one) 
        if row ==5:
            del LE[column]
            LE.insert(column, one)         
        if row ==6:
            del LF[column]
            LF.insert(column, one)  
        if row ==7:
            del LG[column]
            LG.insert(column, one)
    elif rowB == numa and column  == numb:
        if row ==1:
            del LA[column]
            LA.insert(column, one)
        if row ==2:
            del LB[column]
            LB.insert(column, one)     
        if row ==3:
            del LC[column]
            LC.insert(column, one)   
        if row ==4:
            del LD[column]
            LD.insert(column, one) 
        if row ==5:
            del LE[column]
            LE.insert(column, one)         
        if row ==6:
            del LF[column]
            LF.insert(column, one)  
        if row ==7:
            del LG[column]
            LG.insert(column, one)       
    elif row == numa and columA  == numb: 
        if row ==1:
            del LA[column]
            LA.insert(column, one)
        if row ==2:
            del LB[column]
            LB.insert(column, one)     
        if row ==3:
            del LC[column]
            LC.insert(column, one)   
        if row ==4:
            del LD[column]
            LD.insert(column, one) 
        if row ==5:
            del LE[column]
            LE.insert(column, one)         
        if row ==6:
            del LF[column]
            LF.insert(column, one)  
        if row ==7:
            del LG[column]
            LG.insert(column, one)
    elif row  == numa and columB == numb:
        if row ==1:
            del LA[column]
            LA.insert(column, one)
        if row ==2:
            del LB[column]
            LB.insert(column, one)     
        if row ==3:
            del LC[column]
            LC.insert(column, one)   
        if row ==4:
            del LD[column]
            LD.insert(column, one) 
        if row ==5:
            del LE[column]
            LE.insert(column, one)         
        if row ==6:
            del LF[column]
            LF.insert(column, one)  
        if row ==7:
            del LG[column]
            LG.insert(column, one)        
    else:
        if row ==1:
            del LA[column]
            LA.insert(column, blank)
        if row ==2:
            del LB[column]
            LB.insert(column, blank)     
        if row ==3:
            del LC[column]
            LC.insert(column, blank)   
        if row ==4:
            del LD[column]
            LD.insert(column, blank) 
        if row ==5:
            del LE[column]
            LE.insert(column, blank)         
        if row ==6:
            del LF[column]
            LF.insert(column, blank)  
        if row ==7:
            del LG[column]
            LG.insert(column, blank) 



if row ==1:
    del LA[column]
    LA.insert(column, MINE)
if row ==2:
    del LB[column]
    LB.insert(column, MINE)     
if row ==3:
    del LC[column]
    LC.insert(column, MINE)   
if row ==4:
    del LD[column]
    LD.insert(column, MINE) 
if row ==5:
    del LE[column]
    LE.insert(column, MINE)         
if row ==6:
    del LF[column]
    LF.insert(column, MINE)  
if row ==7:
    del LG[column]
    LG.insert(column, MINE)
print("", LA, "\n" , LB, "\n" , LC, "\n" , LD, "\n" , LE, "\n" ,
      LF, "\n" , LG, "\n")
print("Game over")

input("Press enter to quit")
```

Comment: What are the `....` in your code?

Comment: if row ==2: then if row ==3 ...till row == 7really repetitive.

Comment: If you're asking us to fix your dots, then I'd say that this question is too localized. If instead you have an error or are stuck at some point, ask about that. You can [edit] your question and improve it. -- P.S. Welcome to SO, and don't forget to read the [faq] :)

Comment: i just put up all the code ive done.my problem is that the while loop ends if the row entered is also the row the mine is on.

Comment: Even though I appreciate your effort (I really do), now is worse than before. You should try to focus your question on the problem your facing, and posting the minimun amount of code that will show your problem. If you're going to skip bits of your code leave a small comment (only where needed). It's not simple to write a good question, if you want some tips you can find something [here](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18614/177799). (I know that the first time it might be hard to keep up with the SO "standards", but hold on because it'll be worth it)

Comment: Rather than deleting and inserting items into your map, why don't you just modify your list in place? Replace `del LC[column]    LC.insert(column, MINE)` with `LC[column] = MINE`

Comment: I suspect all this repetitive code is most probably not needed. Also, there are some objects in python that allow indexing with row and column like `object[1,2]`, or just nested lists, then `list[1][2]`.

Comment: yeah... i just started with python, haven't learned many shortcuts yet. Thanks Joel. That helps a lot. wish I knew that before I entered all that code in :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in the loop condition:

```
while row != numa and column != numb:
```

That will enter the loop only if there is no mine in **either** the row or the column. You need to combine them with or, not with and:

```
while row != numa or column != numb:
```

This way it will enter the loop unless both the row and the column corresponds to the position the mine is on.